# How do I get the wx.Choice from changing when scrolling while using wxPython?

Tags: python, wxpython

I am very new to wx python. I have a wx.choice box and the problem is that whenever I press a key down or up when I try to scroll down(with the mouse or the key) the panel, the option that i have indicated changes. I have heard that one needs to include event.Skip() but where in the code should it go?

Comment: Post your code and someone can show you! It will be the last line in the function that you `Bind` the `wx.Choice` to.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony the line is Event.Skip() or something else? Unfortunately, I cannot post the code.

Comment: Is it a secret?

Comment: @RolfofSaxony I do not have access to it at the moment

Comment: Edit your question when you do, then someone can help.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony thanks for your help!